# Android: DatePicker spinner text color white on some devices

Tags: android, datepicker

I realized that on some devices my `DatePicker`'s spinners don't show because the text is white instead of black (as it should be).

**Example with a Honor 5C:**

[image]

**Example with a One Plus 5:**

[image]

I realized it by setting a black background color instead:

[image]

I tried to change a lot of different attributes but nothing worked.

Here is the underlying code:

```
final AlertDialog.Builder datePickerDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext(), R.style.AlertDialog);
final View view = fragment.getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.views_form_pick_date_dialog_day, null);
final AppCompatTextView datePickerDialogTitle = (AppCompatTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.views_form_pick_date_dialog_title);
final DatePicker datePickerDialogSpinner = (DatePicker) view.findViewById(R.id.views_form_pick_date_dialog_spinner);
datePickerDialogSpinner.updateDate(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
datePickerDialog.setView(view);
datePickerDialog.show();
```

The XML layout associated:

**R.layout.views_form_pick_date_dialog_day**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView style="@style/TextViewBody"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="@dimen/style_size_space_medium"
        android:background="@color/style_color_red"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:id="@+id/views_form_pick_date_dialog_title" />

    <DatePicker
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/views_form_pick_date_dialog_title"
        android:calendarViewShown="false"
        android:datePickerMode="spinner"
        android:id="@+id/views_form_pick_date_dialog_spinner" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If possible, make sure you are using Support libraries so that the interface appears the same on all framework versions.

Comment: Have you found an answer for this?

Answer (score 1):

Change the datePicker textColor  by simply doing this:

```
 <DatePicker
        android:id="@+id/start_date_text"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="190dp"
        android:datePickerMode="spinner"
        android:calendarViewShown="false"
        style="@style/MyDatePicker" />
```

and style

```
<style name="MyDatePicker" parent="android:Widget.Material.Light.DatePicker">
     <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/Black</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set style for your date picker

```
<style name="datepicker" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/primary</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

Use this as your Activity style.

```
<style parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" name="MyActivityTheme">

<!-- Customize your theme here. -->

<item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>

<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>

<item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>

<item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

<item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/black</item>


</style>
```

and in your manifest add its as your Activity theme.

```
<activity
        android:name="yourActivity"
        android:theme="@style/MyActivityTheme"/>
```

it may help you.